# How do I claim rewards on polygon aave with smart contract?

Tags: solidity, aave

What is the function to claim rewards on polygon aave? I can't seem to find it in its docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To claim rewards on AAVE, use the IncentiveController. You can find its interface at https://github.com/aave/aave-stake-v2/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IAaveIncentivesController.sol. For Polygon, it is deployed at https://polygonscan.com/address/0x357D51124f59836DeD84c8a1730D72B749d8BC23.